# Auto Fill Magento Attribute based on another Magento Attribute Entity

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, automation, autocomplete

I have multiple custom attributes in Magento.
Several share very similar names and serve the same purpose, yet the entities are different.

IE: Attribute One: Strap Color (eBay); Attribute Two: Strap Color (Amazon)
For the Attribute One (eBay) the entity would be: Beige whereas for the Attribute Two (Amazon) the entity would be: Cream

What I am looking to achieve is, when I enter entity Beige into Attribute One - this should automatically fill Attribute Two`s entity as Cream

Same goes to many other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Use Store Views, giving alternate names to each attribute options per store view (allows inheritance when values are blank)

If you want to manage eBay and Amazon with Magento I've found it invaluable to configure multiple Store Views (eg. English, eBay En, Amaozn En). This way when you add attribute options you can then leave the other store views blank to automatically inherit the admin value, or override it at the appropriate store view level.

**Example:**
This works great for the eBay attribute 'Condition', as eBay expects it's attribute id values here... not the textual description (1000 = Brand New etc...)

Attribute: Condition

- Option 1 (Admin view): New
- Option 1 (eBay view): 1000
- Option 1 (Amazon): Brand New
- Option 2 (Admin view): Used
- Option 2 (eBay view): 2000
- Option 2 (Amazon): Used